# HtmlUnit - Button click issues

Tags: java, spring, button, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am coding up a server in java, and for part of the server I need a webscraper. To scrape the website, I need to log in and the web scraper works perfectly when running as a main method, but when ran on the server, the button click does not redirect to a new page. Here is the code.

```
    String loginUrl="MY_URL";
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    WebClientOptions options=web.getOptions();
    web.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    options.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    options.setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    options.setCssEnabled(false);
    options.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    options.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    options.setRedirectEnabled(true);
    try {
        final HtmlPage firstPage = (HtmlPage)web.getPage(loginUrl);
        final HtmlForm form = firstPage.getForms().get(0);
        final HtmlTextInput userNameField = form.getInputByName("USER");
        userNameField.setValueAttribute("MY_USERNAME");
        final HtmlPasswordInput passWordField = form.getInputByName("PASSWORD");
        passWordField.setValueAttribute("MY_PASSWORD");
        HtmlButton button =(HtmlButton)firstPage.getElementById("safeLoginbtn");
        System.out.println(firstPage.getUrl().toString());
        button.click();
        System.out.println(web.getEnclosedPage().getUrl().toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When running this in a main method, the two print statements show two different pages, the log in page and the page behind the log in respectively. But when running on a server, the two print statements have nearly the same url, and both are urls for the log in page. Why could this be happening? Why does the code act differently in a main method compared to being run on the server?

The server is being run by a Spring framework if that has any thing to do with it.

EDIT:
Example here:

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.facebook.com");
    HtmlForm form = page1.getForms().get(0);
    HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue("Log In").get(0);
    HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("email");
    textField.setValueAttribute("email@email.com");
    HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = form.getInputByName("pass");
    textField2.setValueAttribute("MY_PASS");
    HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    System.out.println(page2.asText());
```

This works in a main method of a java application, but when run on the server by Spring's scheduled annotation, it will not log me in.

Comment: `HtmlPage page2 = button.click();` and then check `page2.asXml()`. You can also post your complete case with the URL, please read http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/submittingJSBugs.html

Comment: @AhmedAshour I edited the post to give an example

Comment: Interesting, can you post minimal Spring project, so we can debug further.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a redirect in the way. Perhaps you can do the following:

```
HtmlPage pageAfterLogin = button.fireEvent("onclick").getNewPage();
System.out.println(pageAfterLogin.getUrl().toString());
```

Comment: Still no luck with this method

Comment: No, nothing errors out, it just does not perform as expected. Why would it perform different on a server compared to in a java application?